# Perform ANOVA (using ezANOVA) iteratively on grouped data

Tags: r, anova

Create sample_data:

```
norm_power <- rnorm(2298) 
phoneme <- c("t", "v", "s", "p")
intensity <- c("loud", "soft")
unique_ID <- as.factor(rep(c("elec1", "elec2", "elec3", "elec4", "elec5", "elec6", "elec7",
                   "elec8", "elec9", "elec10"), length.out = 2298))

Subject <- as.factor(rep(c("DBS1", "DBS2", "DBS3", "DBS4"), length.out = 2298))    
sample_data <- data.frame(norm_power, unique_ID, Subject, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
sample_data$intensity[sample(1:nrow(sample_data), nrow(sample_data), FALSE)] <- rep(intensity, c(1149,1149))    
sample_data$phoneme[sample(1:nrow(sample_data), nrow(sample_data), FALSE)] <- rep(phoneme, c(574, 574, 575, 575))
```

I am trying to perform an ANOVA and extract coefficients on multiple subsets of my sample data - see above.  When I filter the dataset into individual electrodes (i.e. "elec1"), I am able to get a result (see output):

```
sample_data_elec1 <- filter(sample_data, unique_ID == "elec1")

output <-ezANOVA(dv = norm_power, within=.(phoneme, intensity), wid=Subject, data=sample_data_elec1)
```

However, when I try to complete a similar operation on multiple 'subsets' of sample_data at a  time, I just produce NAs for all operations.  See 'anova_data' below:

```
get_coefs <-function(d){

  output <-ezANOVA(dv = norm_power, within=.(phoneme, intensity), wid=Subject, data=d)

  tibble('phoneme_F' = output[["ANOVA"]][[4]][1], "phoneme_pval" = output[["ANOVA"]][[5]][1], 
         "intensity_F" = output[["ANOVA"]][[4]][2], "intensity_pval" = output[["ANOVA"]][[5]][2], 
         "interact_F" = output[["ANOVA"]][[4]][3], "interact_pval"= output[["ANOVA"]][[5]][3])
}

anova_data <- sample_data %>% 
  group_by(unique_ID) %>% 
  do({get_coefs(.)}) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Thank you in advance for your help - please let me know if I can clarify further!!

Comment: the individual tests don't always work when I try this.  i get various errors from the anova command itself.

Comment: do you think that the anova_data  data frame is populated by NAs because some of the individual tests aren't working?  I would think that in that case some rows would be NA while some are populated...

Comment: when i try your code i can't get the anova_data line to run at all because of the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you are running a test for repeated measure anova. It has a very strict design, using the example from [this website](http://coltekin.net/cagri/R/r-exercisesse5.html):

```
library(ez)
bilingual=read.delim("http://coltekin.net/cagri/R/data/bilingual.txt")
# this works
ezANOVA(data=bilingual,dv=mlu,wid=.(subj),
within=.(language, age), between=gender)
```

And you can see for every subject, you have exactly 1 measurement for before / after or combination of each factor essentially.

```
table(bilingual$age,bilingual$language,bilingual$subj)

, ,  = 1


              home.only school
  firstgrade          1      1
  preschool           1      1
  secondgrade         1      1

, ,  = 2


              home.only school
  firstgrade          1      1
  preschool           1      1
  secondgrade         1      1
```

Going back to your example, you need to use `within_full` since you have more than one measurement, some of your example dataset will work, but you can see there's a few complains, and rightfully so because the design isn't meant for this test:

```
output <-ezANOVA(dv = norm_power,between=.(phoneme, intensity), within_full=.(phoneme, intensity), wid=.(Subject), data=droplevels(sample_data_elec1))
```

And you are also missing the between effect, which I have filled in for you above, according to repeated measure. Now if your study or test is not meant for [repeated measure anova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design), then just put all the variables you would like to test under between:

```
output <-ezANOVA(dv = norm_power,between=.(phoneme, intensity), wid=.(Subject), data=droplevels(sample_data_elec1))
```